# java simple UI loop, can't find bug

Tags: java, loops, exception

I've written the UI class below and it's basically just a simple loop that calls a couple of methods in the class, console based ui.

The user is supposed to be able to select from 1 of 6 menu choices. Now, the selection input from the user must be of type int. I surrounded the selection code with a try {} catch{} to handle an invalid, non-int, input.

So when I test it everything works fine. Right now if the user inputs a valid selection, an int of 1,2,3,4,5, or 0 then it's stuck in the while loop. This isn't the bug I just haven't implemented the menu choices yet.

The bug appears when the user enters a non-int invalid input. Maybe I have done something funky with the exception handling, not sure, but if you put in an invalid input it just loops endlessly as if an invalid input is being entered over and over even if I input nothing. It seems like it's getting input from somewhere else but I have no idea what could be sending input to the Scanner.

I know I have other Scanner objects but they're not even in the same class and aren't connected to this class at all yet. I was hoping someone else could take a look at it and maybe tell me what I've got wrong.

```
class UI{
    private Scanner userInput;
    private String fileName;
    private Performance perf;

    private Menu menu;
    private int selection = -1;

    public UI(){
        userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        setFileName();
        initializePerformance();
        initializeMenu();
        loopUI();
    }

    void setFileName() {
        System.out.print("\nEnter the performance file name: ");
        try{
            fileName = userInput.next();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            setFileName();
        }
    }

    void initializePerformance(){
        perf = new Performance(fileName);
    }

    void initializeMenu(){
        this.menu = new Menu();
        menu.addItem("Rows");
        menu.addItem("Show Row");
        menu.addItem("Seat Status");
        menu.addItem("Buy Ticket");
        menu.addItem("Return Ticket");
        menu.addItem("Exit and Save");
    }

    void showMenu(){
        menu.showMenu();
    }

    void selection() {
        System.out.println("\nSelection[1,2,3,4,5,0]: ");
        try{
            this.selection = userInput.nextInt();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Invalid selection, try again.");
        }
    }

    void loopUI(){
        while(selection != 0){
            System.out.println("\n" + perf.getName());
            showMenu();
            selection();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add `userInput.next()` within the catch clause to consume the rest of the line after using `userInput.nextInt()`.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. May I ask why that is though? Is it a new line character that I'm missing?

Comment: @user90376 When using `nextInt()` there is indeed still characters to be consumed. You do that using  `next()`